# Xamarin.iOS Building to a Remote Mac Build host

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

I have built a Xamarin.iOS application. It compiles fine.

When it is sent to the build host (Mac Book Pro), I get an error about the Main.storyboard not being accessible.

I have even tried it with a dummy sample application See below:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       2016-06-07 15:40:22.661 ibtoold[11380:255825] Exception raised while unarchiving document objects - Unexpected element "accessibilityConfiguration" for key "traits" while decoding "accessibility".    HelloIOS

The firewall on the Mac is disabled so its not being blocked, but what would cause the file to not be accessible?

Comment: I encountered today exactly the same error. I'm using a Mac Mini als Build Host from Visual Studio No Idea what's the reason

Comment: As a workaround I deleted the part with "accessibilityConfiguration" for key "traits" with the code editor from the storyboard file. after that I could compile again

Comment: @Thomas what exactly did you delete? Could you please show a snippet somehow? Cheers

Comment: I don't have the original code anymore, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this when I set a button as 'selected' by default. In the .storyboard file, it looked like this

```
<accessibility key="accessibilityConfiguration">
     <accessibilityConfiguration key="traits" button="YES" selected="YES"/>
</accessibility>
```

I removed it and now my project builds and deploys.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this error when you have a method implementation without the button being enabled or after removing the button.